# Can I deploy to Lion 64 bit and Snow Leopard 32 bit?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, xcode4.2

I'm developing an app on a 64-bit machine with Lion and Xcode 4.2. I'm not doing anything special with the 64bit environment or lion specifically and would like this app to run on 32bit Snow Leopard machines. Can I do this? If so, what specifically do I set in the build settings?

I've looked all over the internet and cannot find a simple "yes, here's how..." or a "no, it isn't possible"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to the situation above: NO

Because the program was using ARC and that is limited to 64 bit releases only.